# How to insert Italian language in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

In present condition i am inserting some Italian data in phpmyadmin, when i display the same data in client side question mark(?) appearing

following data i am storing in db

```
  Ditta giovane e dinamica, con esperienza pluridecennale nel settore, si avvale delle più innovative tecniche di modellazione associate alla tradizione artigianale orafa valenzana. Specializzata nella produzione di gioielleria classica, in particolare bracciali tennis e fedine éternelle, rivisitata nel disegno e curata nei particolari, adatta ad una clientela esigente.
```

using pdo to insert data

Comment: can you tell what is **Collation** of that field?

Comment: coalation is  latin1_swedish_ci

Comment: it is stored in itallic lang? can you post your data?

Comment: i am storing the data using addslashes function

Comment: show your data being stored

Comment: change collation to **utf8_general_ci**

Comment: first see in database is it storing data in readble format?

Comment: data is stored in db  collation change  to utf8_general_ci  but still showing question mark

Comment: @jordandap Can you update the post with the following: 1. The data you have inserted (that is displaying incorrectly). 2. The PHP connection you are using to insert this data. 3. Run the query in phpMyAdmin `SHOW CREATE TABLE yourTable` (replace yourTable with actual table-name), and post the results.

Comment: looks like you meant to say italian, not italic..

Comment: hint: phpmyadmin, nor mysql, give any shits whatsoever what language your input is.

Comment: yes  italian @ Pamblam

Comment: @Pamblam +1 for excellent answer however jordon is looking for solution and this hint might help him.

Comment: Have you checked the default character set of your connection? Here is how to check character sets in use : http://makandracards.com/makandra/2529-show-and-change-mysql-default-character-set Here shows how to set the connection character set : https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/

Comment: @Pamblam: with characters like ù & é - MySQL does give a shit about the language

Comment: yea paul i got that. like i said, i didn't notice them.

Answer (score 2):

Now that we see you ment to say *Italian* instead of *itallic*, there's some more to work with.

You only specified that you use PDO, but let's see if we can't figure out a solution for you.

**Headers**

Setting the charset in both HTML and PHP headers to UTF-8

- PHP: `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`
  *(PHP headers has to be placed before any kind output (echo, whitespace, HTML), so putting it at the top of the file should ensure that)*
- HTML: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`
  *(HTML-headers are placed within the `<head>` / `</head>` tag)*

**Connection**

You also need to specify the charset in the *connection itself*. In PDO, it's specified in the object itself, like this

```
$handler = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');
```

Note the `charset=utf8` attribute in the DSN.

**Database and tables**

- Your *database* and all its tables has to be set to UTF-8. Note that charset is *not* the same as collation.

  You can do that by running the queries below *once* for each database and tables (for example in phpMyAdmin)

  `ALTER DATABASE databasename CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;`
  `ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;`

---

You will need to insert the data again after performing these changes, as what's already in the database has the wrong character encoding. It is possible to create a script to do this, but it could result in a lot more work, so if you have a small database, inserting it again would probably be faster.

Comment: i'm not convinced it's a charset issue, but +1 for a useful answer.

Comment: What makes you think it's not a charset issue? I'm just curious, because normally a question-mark replacing "special" characters would indicate just that (or at least so in my experience).

Comment: @Pamblam: looks very much like a charset problem at some point during query or display.

Comment: yeah, it does. i didn't notice the accented characters.